# Kohana validation. How to use a lambda function to set rule?

Tags: php, validation, anonymous-function, rule, kohana-3.2

I have a problem with Kohana's validation object. For example, I want to check the `user_id` field. It has to be a number and greater then 0. I've tried following:

```
$validation->rule("user_id", function($str){
  return (is_numeric($str) && $str > 0);
}
```

Also I put into the field, just a string "sdfgwertxcvb". But the $validation->check() returns "TRUE". Why?

Please, explain to me what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/kohana/core/blob/3.3/master/classes/Kohana/Validation.php#L192

there is an example how to use it